# Tachanun with No Seats

Tags: tefilla, standing-sitting, tachanun

Many times I'm in Shul and don't have a place to sit for Tachanun. What's proper procedure in such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lean your head on your arm while standing.  At the end of the first paragraph (usually the transition from seated-leaning to seated-normal), stop leaning; at the start of the next paragraph (usually the transition from seated-normal to standing), just stay standing.

Sitting is the preferred position for head-leaning, but not required for it.

Comment: only ashkenazim lean on the arm

Answer (score 8):

If one leans against something to the point that if it were removed he would fall it is considered as if he were sitting. Will give you source when I get a moment.

Comment: very related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/226/759