# Where and how does the Shaliach Tzibbur say Tachanun?

Tags: chazzan-prayer-leader, tachanun, standing-sitting

When the Shaliach Tzibbur says Tachanun, should he leave his position and say it sitting down or should he rather stay in position and say it without physically sitting down but in a manner which is still halachically valid for Tachanun? Related: [Tachanun with No Seats](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/tachanun-with-no-seats)

Comment: Why would you assume that he can't leave his position?

Comment: @ רבותמחשבות I have assumed nothing. I have seen sheluchei tzibbur who remained at the omud and that's why I asked.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for clarifying. Perhaps add that in to the question, as I might otherwise assume that you think there is some reason to avoid sitting down.

Comment: You actually have assumed that it is possible he can't or shouldn't leave his location. The reason you think that is possible is that it explains a surprising behavior you saw someone else do.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות You (and DoubleAA) are right. See my comment to Gershon Gold's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per Rabbi Naftali Hoffner in [Halacha - Nesias Kapayim U'Tachanun 92:3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43404&st=&pgnum=126) the three steps one is supposed to take after Shemona Esrei prior to walking is applicable to the Chazan. The Chazan does these three steps at Kadish Shaleim after the end of Ashrei / Uva Ltzion. Therefore it is proper for the Chazan to not sit down and to say Tachanun at the Amud. He does note that according to the Rambam the Chazan may sit down for the Tachanun.

Comment: Now **there's** an interesting aspect. I assume that this book was written fairly recently, i.e. after O.C.? Reason I ask is that O.C. assumes that Shat"z was also Torah reader. However, currently, it is more common to have a different person read the Torah. So, if I understand Rav Hoffner's ruling, that implies that the shat"z may not sit while the Torah is read?

Comment: @DanF: Instead of assuming why not check the front of the book and see that it is a recent book. Has Haskama from Rabbi Moshe Feinstein Zatzal.

Comment: Thank you. I felt that there had to be some reason as I once heard a Rav advise against sitting down.

Comment: Wouldn't walking around be more of a problem than sitting in place? I don't understand this.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:tf471OOOKr0J:https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp%3Fid%3D17772%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us):

> Tachanun is the only part of davening where the chazzan does not
>   stand. Since the entire purpose of the Tachanun is to recite a prayer
>   while one is bowing, the chazzan also "falls Tachanun."

[This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1793/5275) states that if one is leaning on the amud to the point where he would fall if it were removed, then, it's considered like sitting. Thus, I have seen many *shlichei tzibbur* do this.

As to whether it is **ideal** for one to sit fully on a chair and therefore leave the *amud* to do this - I'm uncertain. I've seen both methods performed. One may question if leaving the *amud* for something possibly unnecessary such as this might be *torach tzibbur*.

Apparently, he doesn't need to leave his position, as I've alluded to, but, is better clarified in the linked question. As to whether it is **ideal** for the chazzan to specifically sit, and if he needs to, can he leave the amud to do that - I don't know, offhand. I have seen chazzanim do that, while others lean, and, both are permitted.

Comment: Thank you for the answer; +1. I have edited the question as a result. I particularly want to know the answer where the shaliach tzibbur has not left the amud but is leaning enough for it not to be called standing.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok In that case, it's considered sitting, which is what he should be doing. You may want to ask a follow up Q, and possibly generalize - "May the Shat"z leave the amud?"

Comment: I have added a word to the question "physically" which I hope helps.

Comment: In my shul, when serving as chazzan, we have been directed to sit for tachanun and not stand until the last paragraph.

Comment: I've edited my answer, as you seem to have  aspects to your question. You might want to ask a follow-up.

Comment: @Dennis If you can discover if that is halacha vs. minhag, feel free to edit that into my answer.

Comment: @DanF It is more anecdotal than anything else.  One person was standing during all of tachanun and was instructed by our rabbi to sit for the tachanun.  I can try to find a source.

Comment: @Dennis Chazzan has different rules. mostly, than the rest of the cong. It's possible that the rav was following the "general" rule that everyone, including the chazzan should sit, and the rav prob. extended that to meaning the chazzan should specifically sit on a chair rather than lean. In my shul, ther eis a bench for the chazzan to sit. Then, again, the chazzan davens from the shulchan (i.e. Torah reader's table) as there is no amud, so there is room for the bench, which is used mainly for *Hagbah*.