# Trying to find a mekor that if someone is leaning on something, it's considered as if he is fully standing on it

Tags: halacha-theory, beis-hamikdash, lomdus, kodshim

I'm learning the gemara in Zvachim 19b that says that if a Kohein is leaning on another Kohein, his avoda is kasher if not for the din amida of לשרת. My question is if this is considered like he is standing on the ritzpa or not, since he is leaning on the Kohein, maybe it's considered as if he is fully on the Kohein and not standing on the ritzpa at all (which is needed for avoda).

I want to be תולה this in a חקירה that I have about the din עמידה על הריצפה, I have a צד that the kdusha flows through the Kohein, so maybe it can flow from one Kohein to another.... but if it's just a din amida, that the Kohein should be standing on the ritzpa, then maybe this wouldn't be good since he's on the Kohein and not on the ritzpa.

Hence my question. Any insight about the question and my חקירה in general much appreciated :)

Edit - I have since found a Gemara that says explicitly that a kohein can’t stand on another kohein and do avoda

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/226/759

Comment: This is a machlokes and Tosfos points out that any leaning is a problem(acc to the Rabbanan) ,one must be able to stand on their own,according to the other opinion leaning on another person is like standing (mashma) also isn't the din of standing here have to do with having aimah?